# Can I reduce noise in blender animation without using denoiser or a higher sample value

Tags: animation, 3d, rendering, blender, noise

I am rendering an animation of an Iphone.

If I use denoiser from compositing or from the Sampling>render>denoise, the transition from one frame to another looks weird. it does not denoise both frame in the same way and the quality drops since denoiser removes most of the details.

So I can obviously use more samples to increase details. but 1st of all the transition from one frame to another is bad and secondly, in 256 samples, my 530 frame animation takes about 13 hours using 0.01 noise threshold. So denoiser is out of the equation.

My question is, Is there any way that I can get less noise and less render time than 13 hours?

These are my render settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj5Pf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uOGu.png)
Btw, I am using persistent data, 1920x1080 resolution and 1920 tile size.